# Missing DLL in my project during compilation

Tags: c++, conan

I'm new to conan/premake, I've made a conanlist and a premake which is suppose to set my project.
But when I execute my project in release mode, I receive `QT6Widgets.dll is missing` and `QT6Core.dll is missing`. I don't know how to fix that. Here is my conanfile

```
[requires]
glfw/3.3@bincrafters/stable
qt/6.0.1@bincrafters/stable
boost/1.75.0
[generators]
premake
```

and this is the premake I've made

```lua
include "build/conanbuildinfo.premake.lua"

workspace "TileEditor"
    conan_basic_setup()

    configurations
    {
        "Debug",
        "Release",
        "Dist"
    }

outputdir = "%{cfg.buildcfg}-%{cfg.system}-%{cfg.architecture}"

project "TileEditor"
    location "TileEditor"
    kind "WindowedApp"
    language "C++"

    targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir ("bin-obj/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

    linkoptions { conan_exelinkflags }

    files
    {
        "**.h", "**.cpp" 
    }

    filter "configurations:Debug"
    defines { "DEBUG" }
    symbols "On"

    filter "configurations:Release"
    defines { "NDEBUG" }
    optimize "On"
```

Comment: You need to copy the dlls to your executable directory or add them to your path. The dlls aren't missing (or required) during compilation, they're missing at runtime

Comment: @AlanBirtles ok but conan is suppose to download/install and set everything automatically, how should I know where this files are located ?

Comment: You need to tell Conan you want that behaviour https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/using_packages/conanfile_txt.html#imports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic Link Libraries or DLL for short, is not linked to your application at compile time. The library type that gets liked at compile time are static libraries (`.lib` files).

By default when you try executing an application, the system will check if the required DLL is in the working directory (in the directory which the application is placed). If not found, it'll check in the default system directory. If that fails too, an error will be popped.

So to resolve your issue, copy the `QT6Widgets.dll` and `QT6Core.dll` files from your Qt installation directory, and place them in your application's working directory.

Comment: ok but conan set everything automatically, how should I know where this files are located ?

Comment: Use conan info --path command to discover where artifacts are installed: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/consumer/info.html. Anyway, .DLL files MUST be installed in bin/ folder, it's a Visual Studio convention, Conan follows same.